# IRC Client C# PING request

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcpclient, irc

I'm trying to write my own IRC Client an i think i'm stuck where i should send the PONG response.
Everything my code currently does, is sending the logon informations ("NICK USERNAME" and "USER USERNAME...")
That works so far, but the server quits my connection after that.
This is what the server says:

```
:eu.german-elite.net NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...
:eu.german-elite.net NOTICE AUTH :*** Found your hostname (cached)
:eu.german-elite.net NOTICE AUTH :*** Checking ident...
:eu.german-elite.net NOTICE AUTH :*** No ident response; username prefixed with
~
ERROR :Closing Link: [91.115.212.209] (Ping timeout)
```

Shouldn't i get a PING request after that?
If so, where is it? (on another port?)

Comment: You should get a PING over that tcp connection at some point (perhaps something else comes first, I don't remember). But you didn't post enough code to see if you're correctly checking for responses from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The server should send a PING request to you on the same port as all the other stuff, built up like this:
`PING <stuff>`
Note that it is missing the colon in front, it expects a reply like this:
`PONG <stuff>` while `<stuff>` is unchanged.